# Scheduling pthreads in Round-robin method

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a multi-threaded server application.The server accepts connections from multiple devices and assign each connection a thread.The thread is a looping thread i.e it uses a while loop which iterates until the client closes the connection.

Currently when multiple clients got connected to the server only single client is able to communicate i.e the data sent by a single device is received at the server side and updated in database the other devices remain connected to server but no data is received from them. what seems the reason to me (not sure only assuming) is that only a single thread remains executing and other threads don't get the turn to execute.

so I want to schedule threads in round robin so that each thread executes.How can I schedule threads in round robin

I got the following code on-line but it was not able to schedule the threads in round robin.

```
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
  pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_RR);
```

Here is my code which creates threads:

```
connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,(socklen_t*)&clntSock);

 if(connfd > 0){  
     conn_desc = connfd;
     puts("Connection accepted");

if(pthread_create( &thr, &attr ,  connection_handler , (void*)&conn_desc) < 0){    
  perror("could not create thread");
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that has the problem, and maybe someone call tell you what's actually wrong, instead of just messing with random settings that won't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing any of your threading code, there is no way to know what the problem is. It would be most useful to know where and how you were attempting to fork the threads, and how you were attempting to receive connection data from each one.

Comment: I can't say what the problem is, but I can say with confidence that the problem is not the pthreads scheduler setting.  The default pthreads thread scheduler will schedule multiple threads to run in parallel also (otherwise there would be no point in using pthreads with the default thread scheduler).

Comment: `conn_desc = connfd; pthread_create(...,  (void*)&conn_desc);` - it looks really unsafe and may cause you problems later

Comment: You don't need multiple threads to serve multiple network connections, you can achieve the same using `select()`. The part concerning the traffic itself can be handled that way, the part handling the actual content may benefit from multiple threads. If your design isn't set yet, I'd move to a slightly higher-level data exchange framework like e.g. ZeroMQ.

Comment: Because your code has a bug you're going to mess with scheduling? Wtf?! Will that magically fix whatever bug is causing your threads to block each other?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is *not* related to the scheduler policy. You have a potential race condition in your code.

```
// parent thread
while (1) {
    listen(...);

    connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,
        (socklen_t*) &clntSock);

    conn_desc = connfd;
    pthread_create(&thr,&attr,connection_handler,(void*) &conn_desc);
}

// child thread function
void *
connection_handler(void *ptr)
{
    int fildes = *(int *) ptr;
    ...
    return (void *) 0;
}
```

The race is that the parent can fire a second thread *before* the first thread has been able to dereference `ptr`. Thus, two threads will use the *same* value for `connfd`.

---

To correct this, we need to slightly modify the calling sequence to a pass-by-value:

```
// parent thread
while (1) {
    listen(...);

    connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,
        (socklen_t*) &clntSock);

    pthread_create(&thr,&attr,connection_handler,(void*) connfd);
}

// child thread function
void *
connection_handler(void *ptr)
{
    int fildes = (int) ptr;
    ...
    return (void *) 0;
}
```

*Side note:* It is guaranteed that an `int` can be passed inside a pointer in this manner, but for sticklers, see below.

---

```
// parent thread
while (1) {
    listen(...);

    connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,
        (socklen_t*) &clntSock);

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = connfd;

    pthread_create(&thr,&attr,connection_handler,(void*) ptr);
}

// child thread function
void *
connection_handler(void *ptr)
{
    int fildes = *(int *) ptr;
    free(ptr);
    ...
    return (void *) 0;
}
```